# List all contacts in a table with JSON

Tags: php, json, contacts

I'm currently using this function to get all my contacts from Google Contacts.

```
session_start();

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data = array(
    'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
    'Email' => 'email',
    'Passwd' => 'password',
    'source'=>'sourcetest',
    'service'=>'cp'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


$responses = explode("\n", curl_exec($ch));
$_SESSION['auth'] = str_replace('Auth=', '', $responses[2]);
$_SESSION['email'] = 'email';



$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full';
$url .= '?group=http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/'.$_SESSION['email'].'/base/6';
$url .= '&max-results=500&alt=json';

$ch = curl_init($url);

$header[] = 'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='.$_SESSION['auth'];
$header[] = 'GData-Version: 3.0';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

To print the whole JSON works fine with `echo $respone;` but I don't know how to list all of the contacts (full name, phone and image/avatar) in a table. I have tried `json_decode()` and even Google'd for a solution for a few days now with no result.

I'm asking you know - how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
Array
(
    [version] => 1.0
    [encoding] => UTF-8
    [feed] => Array
        (
            [xmlns] => http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
            [xmlns$openSearch] => http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/
            [xmlns$gContact] => http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008
            [xmlns$batch] => http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch
            [xmlns$gd] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005
            [gd$etag] => W/"{code}"
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [$t] => mymail@gmail.com
                )

            [updated] => Array
                (
                    [$t] => 2011-11-07T13:50:54.073Z
                )

            [category] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                            [term] => http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact
                        )

                )

            [title] => Array
                (
                    [$t] => edgren's Contacts
                )

            [link] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => alternate
                            [type] => text/html
                            [href] => http://www.google.com/
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed
                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mymail%40gmail.com/full
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post
                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mymail%40gmail.com/full
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch
                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mymail%40gmail.com/full/batch
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [rel] => self
                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mymail%40gmail.com/full?alt=json&max-results=500&group=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds%2Fgroups%2Fmymail%40gmail.com%2Fbase%2F6
                        )

                )

            [author] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [$t] => edgren
                                )

                            [email] => Array
                                (
                                    [$t] => mymail@gmail.com
                                )

                        )

                )

            [generator] => Array
                (
                    [version] => 1.0
                    [uri] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds
                    [$t] => Contacts
                )

            [openSearch$totalResults] => Array
                (
                    [$t] => 73
                )

            [openSearch$startIndex] => Array
                (
                    [$t] => 1
                )

            [openSearch$itemsPerPage] => Array
                (
                    [$t] => 500
                )

            [entry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [gd$etag] => "{code}"
                            [id] => Array
                                (
                                    [$t] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mymail%40gmail.com/base/{code}
                                )

                            [updated] => Array
                                (
                                    [$t] => 2011-09-12T17:28:57.835Z
                                )

                            [app$edited] => Array
                                (
                                    [xmlns$app] => http://www.w3.org/2007/app
                                    [$t] => 2011-09-12T17:28:57.835Z
                                )

                            [category] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                                            [term] => http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact
                                        )

                                )

                            [title] => Array
                                (
                                    [$t] => {contacts name}
                                )

                            [link] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo
                                            [type] => image/*
                                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/mymail%40gmail.com/{code}
                                            [gd$etag] => "{code}"
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => self
                                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mymail%40gmail.com/full/{code}
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => edit
                                            [type] => application/atom+xml
                                            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mymail%40gmail.com/full/{code}
                                        )

                                )

                            [gd$name] => Array
                                (
                                    [gd$fullName] => Array
                                        (
                                            [$t] => {contacts name}
                                        )

                                    [gd$givenName] => Array
                                        (
                                            [$t] => {contacts last name}
                                        )

                                    [gd$familyName] => Array
                                        (
                                            [$t] => {contacts first name}
                                        )

                                )

                            [gContact$birthday] => Array
                                (
                                    [when] => {contacts birthday}
                                )

                            [gd$email] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other
                                            [address] => {contacts email}
                                            [primary] => true
                                        )

                                )

                            [gd$phoneNumber] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile
                                            [$t] => {contacts number}
                                        )

                                )

                            [gd$structuredPostalAddress] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home
                                            [gd$formattedAddress] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$t] => {contacts address}
                                                )

                                            [gd$street] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$t] => {contacts address}
                                                )

                                            [gd$postcode] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$t] => {contacts address}
                                                )

                                            [gd$city] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$t] => {contacts address}
                                                )

                                            [gd$region] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [$t] => {contacts address}
                                                )

                                            [gd$country] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [code] => SE
                                                    [$t] => Sverige
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [gContact$website] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array


        (
                                        [href] => {contacts website}
                                        [rel] => profile
                                    )

                            )

                        [gd$extendedProperty] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => workAddrTB
                                        [value] => WorkAddress2=/WorkCity=/WorkState=/WorkZipCode=/WorkCountry=
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => homeAddrTB
                                        [value] => HomeAddress2=/HomeCity=/HomeState=/HomeCountry=Sverige/HomeZipCode=
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => contactTB
                                        [value] => PreferMailFormat=0/allowRemoteContent=
                                    )

                            )

                        [gContact$groupMembershipInfo] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [deleted] => false
                                        [href] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/mymail%40gmail.com/base/6
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [deleted] => false
                                        [href] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/mymail%40gmail.com/base/d
                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

Comment: What does `$response` look like?

Comment: 1. Please post the content of $response and 2. what is the error when you try json_decode?

Comment: @deceze If you have any contacts in your Gmail account, you can test the code for yourself and see :) I will not expose my contacts for anyone except my self, of course. Besides, the result is gigantic to be posted here.

Comment: Oh come on, a *sample* will do... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the JSON that is returned valid? You could paste the result into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and see if it returns errors.

`json_decode()` should return `NULL` for invalid input. Try using `var_dump(json_decode($response)`. Does it return `NULL` or some other value?

Also, you should be aware that `json_decode()` returns an object by default, so doing something like `echo $response['somekey'];` wouldn't work. To get an associative array, use `json_decode($response, true);`.

---

Edit: The `foreach` was just an example. At the time, you didn't post any output, so I had to guess what would be returned.

If you decode the JSON response into an array, you can iterate over the results using `foreach`, from your sample, it seems that the contacts are in `$the_array["feed"]["entries"]`.

A crude example that should to output a table, if I interpreted the sample correctly:

```
<?php
$response_as_array = json_decode($response, true);
if(isset($response_as_array['feed']) and isset($response_as_array['feed']['entry']))
{   
    echo '<table border="1">'. "\n";
    foreach($response_as_array['feed']['entries'] as $i = > $entry)
    {
        $info = array(
            'title'         => $entry['title'],
            'fullName'      => $entry['gd$name']['gd$fullName']['$t'],
            'givenName'     => $entry['gd$name']['gd$givenName']['$t'],
            'familyName'    => $entry['gd$name']['gd$familyName']['$t'],
            'birthday'      => $entry['gContact$birthday']['when'],
            'email'         => (isset($entry['gd$email'][0]) 
                ? $entry['gd$email'][0]['address'] : ''),
            'phoneNumber'   => (isset($entry['gd$phoneNumber'][0]) 
                ? $entry['gd$phoneNumber'][0][$t] : ''),
            // and so on
        );

        // If this is the first time this loop is run, 
        // then we want to output the column names.
        if($i === 0) {
            echo '<tr>'. "\n";
            foreach(array_keys($info) as $column_name) {
                echo '<th>'. $column_name .'</th>';
            }
            echo '</tr>' . "\n";
        }

        echo '<tr>'. "\n";
        foreach($info as $value) {
            echo '<td>'. $value .'</td>'. "\n";
        }
        echo '</tr>'. "\n";
    }
    echo '</table>'. "\n";
}
```

Note that you can't use double quotes around the keys (such as $entry["gd$name"]) unless you escape them like so: $entry["gd\$name"]. If you use single quotes, you won't have to do that.

If the API doesn't always return all fields (for example, if you haven't filled in a birthdate for the user, the API might return an empty field or it might not return the `gContact$birthday` object/ array at all. In that case, you'll need to build in some checks that double-check that a field exists before trying to get the value, of course. Otherwise, you'd get warnings or errors.

Comment: Thanks! `var_dump(json_decode($response));` prints almost everything. The first sections (the feed-information) prints just fine, but when the array(?) comes to my contacts, it just prints `6 => object(stdClass)[177] ...`, `7 => object(stdClass)[206] ...`, `8 => object(stdClass)[231] ...` and so on. What should I do now?

Comment: The output you're seeing means that you're decoding the JSON string as an object. You'd be better off just using arrays, since you'll probably be more familiar with them. In that case, use `var_dump(json_decode($response, true));`. You'll see that it'll print something that is more readable. If you want even more readable output, use `print_r(json_decode($response, true));`.

Eventually, you'd have something like this (I don't what the API returns, just an example!):

`$array = json_decode($response, true);   foreach($array["entries"] as $entry) {   echo "Name: " . $entry["name"]; }`

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...` with this foreach: `foreach($array["entry"] as $entry) {`. See my first post to see how the output looks like.

Comment: Append single quotes around `$entry['gd$phoneNumber'][0][$t]`, like so: `$entry['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t']`. The above is not intended as a complete solution. I skipped things like the address, which shouldn't be too hard to add yourself. :)

Comment: Ah, there you go ^^ Many thanks! But one more problem - how do I get the photo of the contact? I have tried `<img src="'.$entry['link'][0]['href'].'">` and `<img src="'.$_GET[$entry['link'][0]['href']].'">`as the Google Code API documentary or something, says. What do I wrong?

Comment: I think that you can't hotlink to an image like that. Try copy-pasting the URL into your address bar, you'll probably get an error. You'll need to get the href, then download it on your server with cURL. If you get an error (such as 401 - Unauthorized), then you (as-in, your cURL session) probably isn't logged in anymore.

Anyway, after downloading the image, save it somewhere on *your* web server and then link to the image you've just saved, not to Google's version of the image.

Comment: Okej. How should I download the image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after you run `json_decode()` you get an object with a list of all contacts. Now you need to loop through all the contacts (e.g. using a foreach loop)

If you don't know the exact location of  the contacts in you object just print the result of `json_decode()` with `var_dump()` and you will se the whole object with it's childs.

Regards
Tobias